# Weird UI rendered using tailwindcss and Nextjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, layout, tailwind-css

So i was trying out Next.js with typescript and tailwindcss. I did the initial commit and then started modifying the `layout.tsx` file.

This is what I get after running the dev server

[image]

This is the content of `layout.tsx` file:

```js
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Quiz app",
  description: "A simple quiz app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={`${inter.className} bg-slate-700 container mx-auto p-4 text-slate-100`}
      >
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`page.tsx` only has a div with h1 tag in it

Here is the `tailwind.config.js` file content:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

The expected render should've been a continuous background of slate-700 color.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What styles do you see if if you inspect it?

Comment: You seem to have applied a `background-image` `linear-gradient()` to the `<body>` element in some CSS somewhere.

Comment: This is the class that i can see when I inspect.
class="__className_20951f bg-slate-700 container mx-auto p-4 text-slate-100"

Comment: oh wait. It was the globals.css file that had the linear-gradient stuff, that was rendering this. Thanks @Wongjn

Answer (score 1):

I got to know where the issue was. Thanks to @wongjn for pointing this out. It was the `globals.css` file that I haven't checked. It had the linear-gradient settings and stuff that was rendering the output like that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `globals.css` and change the styles for body. So instead of the default gradient, something like this:

```
body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: var(--background-rgb);
}
```

And customize `--background-rgb` as you like.